# Where is documentation for Android Open Source Project?

Tags: android

My company tries to build up a customized android OS. Where can I find the documentation on the Android open source project? I wanna know the structure and modules within the system, relationship among those modules and how to make changes on the lower level frameworks etc. I can find source code and build android platform based on instruction of the site, http://source.android.com/. However there is not enough documents I can find there to help me customize the Android OS.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: XDA developers http://forum.xda-developers.com/ site a great place to start hacking android source.
This article will help you to get started: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1801690

Comment: I am not aware of more public documentation than that. There are [books](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do) and [training](http://www.opersys.com/training/embedded-android) available on the subject.

Comment: @jdu: the site mostly is for application developers.

Comment: @zaingz: good forum. I will go check it out. Thank you !

Comment: @CommonsWare: Great book! Thanks. I can not find such documents either. It's such a big pain to search through source code to figure out how the lower level modules are working.

Comment: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Development this will provide you initial startup for editing the android source code